# how to add functions to onStart () | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, fragment, onstart

I have a problem because I am trying to add an onReceiptsAdd () function to onStart () but I don't know how to make it work. how to add onReceiptsAdd () to onStart ()
here is my code:

```
class ScanFragment : Fragment(), OnReceiptsItemAdd {
    private var _binding: FragmentScanBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val scanVm by viewModels<ScanViewModel>()
    private val adapter = ReceiptsAdapter(this)

    private val SCAN_DEBUG = "SCAN_DEBUG"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentScanBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val value = binding.etBlank.text?.trim().toString()
        val from = binding.etBlank.text?.trim().toString()
        val image = binding.etBlank.text?.trim().toString()
        val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val usersRef = rootRef.collection("receipts")
        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        auth.currentUser?.apply {
            usersRef.document(uid).set(mapOf(
                "id" to uid,
                "from" to from,
                "value" to value,
                "image" to image,
            )).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "User successfully added.")
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", task.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onReceiptsAdd(receipts: dataReceipts, position: Int) {
        scanVm.addFavReceipt(receipts)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by add it to onStart? You mean you just want to call it during `onStart()`? Don't mark it `override` because it doesn't override anything.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I want to call onReceiptAdd in onStart ()

Comment: Call it like any other function. What's stopping you? I see you're implementing an interface, so maybe `override` is OK.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but I don't know how to add onReceiptAdd (call) in onStart ()

Comment: @Tenfour04 do you help me?

Comment: I just can’t understand your question. You’re already calling functions in `onStart()` so you already know how to call functions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but how to call onReceiptAdd in onStart

Comment: That’s the same thing you already said. Call it the same way you call any function. You already know the syntax for calling a function because you’re already doing it with other functions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but I do not know how to do it. It does not work for me!!!!!

Comment: @Tenfour04 do you help me??

Comment: Based on my understanding, you need to call onReceiptsAdd() from adapter, I don't see any extra benefit for calling this from onStart() unless you have some exceptional case. You will not be able to get position attribute while calling it from onStart().